# Global Variables undefined in ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a globals file to set key data needed for the application.  Everything works until you use the browser refresh button.  Once that is clicked, all the data I am loading from the globals.ts file comes back as undefined when the template is loaded.  After the template is loaded, the promise populates the data.  I need the promise data to populate before the ng-template binding.

Notice that I am trying to populate the global data by calling this.globals.init(token) from the app.component.  Then in the helpful-links template I am trying to build a url based on data passed in from the parent component (myAccount.component).   Oddly enough, data in the parent component also uses the globals file, and populates fine.   Where did I go wrong?

-app.component
constructor(public globals: Globals){}

```
async ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.globals.init(token);
    ...
}
```

-Globals.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class Globals {
    
      async init(token:string): Promise<any>{
  
    if(token === undefined || token === '') {
      token =  this.oidcSecurityService.getIdToken();
    }
   const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    console.log(decoded, '<<<<<<<<<---------  decoded!', this.title)
   this.email = decoded.email;

   await this.get('getuserdata', {}).toPromise()
   .then(async (res) => {
       // THIS IS THE NEEDED DATA THAT COMES BACK AFTER THE BINDING.  all except localstorage is undefined
     localStorage.setItem('email', res['body'][0].email);
     this.userRole = res['body'][0].title;
     this.setUserId(res['body'][0].userid);
     this.userid = res['body'][0].userid;
     this.email = res['body'][0].email;
     this.subscriberid = res['body'][0].fk_tk_subscriber_id;
     this.isManagerRole = res['body'][0].title === 'HR Admin' ? true : false;
     this.setTitle(res['body'][0].title);
     this.profilePic = res['body'][0].profilephotourl;
   });
   }
```

-my7Account.component.html file

```
...
<app-tk-helpful-links [glob]='this.globals'></app-tk-helpful-links>
...
```

--helpful-links template

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tk-helpful-links',
  templateUrl: './tk-helpful-links.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tk-helpful-links.component.scss']
})
export class HelpfulLinksComponent implements OnInit {
  
   @Input() glob: Globals;
   public res: {};
  subscription: Subscription;

  async getHelpfulLinks(): Promise<any> {
    if(this.globals.userid === undefined) {
      this.globals.init('');
    }
  
    return this.dataSvc.get(`gethelpfulLinks/${this.glob.userid}/${this.glob.subscriberid}`, {})
    .subscribe(res =>  {
      this.res = res['body'];
   });

  }

  constructor(
    private dataSvc: TkDataService,
    public globals: Globals 
    ) {
  }

   async ngOnInit() {

    this.getHelpfulLinks();

   }

}
```

Comment: Are you using global variables for sharing between components ?

Comment: Yes, I am.  Data is userid, subscriberid, etc.  Data that most pages use

Comment: Did you try using shared data services rather than global variables?

Comment: I am a Scrum Master that does dev work, so a little fuzzy on shared data services.  Will google it and see.

Comment: Sure. I would recommend you this video https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/ .This is super easy to understand.

Comment: If components are completely unrelated it's much more better to use `Ngrx/Store` to manage state/share data.

Comment: shashank - Looks like the foundation of a shared service is BehaviorSubject.  Will implementing the variables as behaviorsubjects in the globals file work in my use case?  Asking since it means spending substantial time refactoring existing code.

Comment: @Chris can you give me information about where are you getting values for your global variables and where are you initializing global variables?

Comment: @shashank I am initializing the globals in the app.component oninit.  In the code above you can see the call from the app.component to the init method in the globals file.  I did change to behavior subject, and it seems they are populating on refresh.

Comment: @chris I would suggest adding the data service where you will have the global variables and update these values from the app component(parent component) now subscribe to that value in the component where you want to use the value. These would be the standard way of doing.